# Как вывести вывод командной строки в CheckedListBox?

Tags: c++, winforms, winapi, файловая-система, malware

У меня есть программа на `с++` с графическим интерфейсом написанная на Visual Studio 2012. Скриншот прикрепил (`mal.jpg`). Программа выполняет сканирование вредоносных файлов (`malware`) по сигнатурам используя инструмент yara и правила по которым определяем тип зловреда. Вы наверное слышали о нем. При нажатии на кнопку "scanning for malware" у меня открывается командная строка, в коде написал - `system("cmd.exe");` Далее мы пишем уже в ком. строке `yara64 -r virusbase.yara С:\Users\..` название папки. и сканируем папку на наличие в ней зловредов. Если сканер найдет вирус то он обязательно выведет его название и путь к нему в ком. строке. [ссылка на скриншот интерфейса моей программы](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/6uWE/KXr9Sdwjt)

Вопрос: А можно ли прописать в коде так чтобы выводить все содержимое ком. строки непосредственно на интерфейс программы, допустим внутрь `checkedlistbox1` чтобы потом можно было бы выбрать галочкой нужный зловред и при нажатии на `button1` удалить его ? как это реализовать? вообще возможно ли это ? я хочу сделать так чтобы командная строка не открывалась и мы вручную все не вводили, а как нибудь прописать в коде команду на сканирование " `yara64 -r virusbase.yara С:\Users\..` название папки. " и чтобы весь процесс, весь вывод выводился сразу на `checkedlistbox1` или на `textbox`. потом хотел бы дальше отметить `malware` и удалить этот файл через интерфейс моей проги. Вообще хотя бы для начала кроме удаления через кнопку все остальное можно ли сделать? Вообщем помогите друзья. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Всё возможно. Например, проект [Yara](https://github.com/VirusTotal/yara) сделать не консольным, а полноценно графическим. Либо внести 
изменения в [консольный проект](https://github.com/VirusTotal/yara/archive/master.zip) такие, чтобы в начале работы 
`main` например, читала реестр или файл с настройками, где будут записаны часто используемые команды.